# React/Flux - Keeping Status Attributes Organized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

It seems pretty common in react/flux to respond to trigger actions that set specific status attributes on your state data for your components to react to by rendering this vs. that.

**Simple example:** User clicks the "complete" button on a to-do list item component, it fires an action that sets `complete: true` on that item in the store, the component re-renders and reacts to that "complete" status attribute by rendering a friendly check-mark.

**Not-so-simple example:** Application starts loading collection of data from your API, so you init your store with `loading: true`, and your component reacts by rendering a spinner. When the load is complete, an action sets `loading: false` so the component will go ahead and render the items...but if there was an error, the action will also trigger `error: true` prompting the component to render some red warning text. Now you've got two toggles to manage, un-set the error flag if you give it another go, etc.

**Really-not-so-simple example:** User clicks the "edit" button on a to-do list item, so you set `editing: true` on that item so the component renders the form instead of the display. Then, the user hits a submit button. Now you've got `editing: true` and `submitting: true` in case you want to prevent a double-submit while the update is in transit. Then, if there's an error, you need to shut `submitting` off but keep `editing` true and add an `error` flag with a message and now if the user just navigates away from the page you've got to clean all that up...

So...how do we keep all this stuff sane? Consistent? Readable? Are there patterns/conventions/utilities for this kind of status data? How do we keep all these status flags separate from our actual data - the stuff we loaded and may want to submit back to the API, without it having to swat away all these additional bits of information we tacked on?

Maybe it all just comes down to writing clean code, but it seems like the kind of domain that there might be more to thank I'm aware of...

Comment: Sounds like you could use a state machine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using flags (booleans), I would recommend having a `currentStatus` field. You can then use constants to give that field a value. Something like...

`var Status = {
  LOADING: 1,
  EDITING: 2
};`

and so on. In the case that you might have more than one state at once (can't come up with a decent example right now), you can use JS' Bitwise ops.

```
Status = {
  LOADING: 1,
  EDITING: 2,
  SUBMITTING: 4,
  SOMETHING_ELSE: 8
};

// Let's say I'm loading and doing something_else
var currentStatus = Status.LOADING + Status.SOMETHING_ELSE;

// Am I editing?
console.log(Status.EDITING & currentStatus); // 0, so no

// Am I doing something_else?
console.log(Status.SOMETHING_ELSE & currentStatus); // non-zero? Then true
```